# Facebook linter complains about multiple og:url, but there is only one

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to make sure my pages in my new blog are absolutely correct when it comes to integration with facebook etc. When I put my URL in the facebook linter at:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

And put: myurl.com?fbrefresh=true

It complains that there are 'More Than One OG URL Specified'. I've checked the source and there is only one og:url, I've also checked it from the bottom link on the linter page itself where there is 'Scraped Url:     See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL' and again I only found one og:url.

So why is it complaining?

The two URLs that according to facebook are in my page are identical!

Comment: Maybe a second pair of eyes would help

Comment: @phwd Good one, but I think I know how to use Ctrl+F!

Comment: Well if we don't know the URL I'm not sure what else we can say other than either you are right and the linter is wrong and you need to file a bug, or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified an OG url in two places

`<!-- Facebook Opengraph -->`
`<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.eve.com.mt/2012/11/16/is-living-abroad-something-for-everyone/">`

and

`<meta property="http://ogp.me/ns#url" content="http://www.eve.com.mt/2012/11/16/is-living-abroad-something-for-everyone/">`

A possible cause for this in WordPress is using having two plugins update meta data at the same time.

If you are using the Official Facebook WordPress plugin, your meta might be inserted from it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes it is the official facebook wordpress plugin. So I can remove my manual insertion then from the header.